# How to increase icon size without getting an overflow error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to display 2 icons in the app bar, one at the left and one at the right.

**My code**

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: FlatButton.icon(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.info,size: 20,color: Colors.white,),
    bottom:TabBar(...),
    actions:Widget<>[...],
```

I'm able to do so, however the size of the icon is too small as you can see below

[image]

If I increase the icon size by more than 20, i get an `overflow` error.

I've also tried wrapping the `FlatButton` widget with a `Wrap` widget but I still get the same result.

How can I increase the size of the icon?

Comment: Try to replace FlatButton.icon with GestureDetector. Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Use PreferredSize:

```
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
    child: Container(
      child: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.info,
          size: 50,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the error you are getting.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Plugin example app'),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.info),
            iconSize: 40.0,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
              iconSize: 40.0,
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Boron do you really want to use `FlatButton`?. Try using `IconButton`  as mentioned above.